# Django URL pattern with a list

Tags: django

I have a list with category names , e.g. `cats = ["tv", "movie", "theater"]`.
I would like to write a url pattern to catch only URLs which contain one of the items in the list, such as:

```
url(r'^site/CATEGORY_NAME/$', 'mainsite.views.home'),
```

so that `CATEGORY_NAME` can only one one of the items in the list cats.
How can I do that?

Thanks,
Meir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build part of a regular expression from the list by using python's string `join` method, and then use that in the URL pattern.

For example:

```
cats = ["tv", "movie", "theater"]
cats_re = '(?:' + '|'.join(cats) + ')'

# ...then...
url(r'^site/' + cats_re + '/$', 'mainsite.views.home'),
```

In this case, the whole regular expression would look like:

```
url(r'^site/(?:tv|movie|theater)/$', 'mainsite.views.home'),
```

Comment: If you also want to pass the category to the view as a named parameter: `url(r'^site/(?P<category>tv|movie|theater)/$', 'mainsite.views.home')`

Answer (score 5):

As URL matching is done based on a regular expression you can use the ability of regular expressions to match multiple strings to do this. The | (pipe) character selects between multiple options, i.e. (a|b|c) will match a, b or c.

```
url(r'^site/(tv|movie|theatre)/$', 'mainsite.views.home'),
```

The [Python regular expression documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is really rather good and worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

For Django 2+ with Python 3+, you can use the following:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

# List of category names defined here:
_entities = ["tv", "movie", "theater"]
re_entities = f'(?P<enertainment>{"|".join(_entities)})'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(f'^{re_entities}/.../$', views.EntertainmentHandler.as_view()),
    ...
    ]
```